# Llamar a la variable de un método desde otra

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables, método

Tengo un bot hecho en **Visual Studio** con **C#** que consume un **Web Service** para realizar operaciones básicas.

El usuario ingresa dos números y ellos deben sumarse, pero no puedo lograrlo. La solución que se me ocurrió a mi, fue pedirle al usuario los dos números en métodos diferentes, pero esto me genera la necesidad de llamar ambas variables desde otro método.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme? Adjunto los métodos que se requieren abajo, muchas gracias.

```
private async Task numero1(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    var activity = await result as Activity;
    var num1 = activity.Text;
    await context.PostAsync($"El primer número es {num1}");
    context.Wait(numero2);
}

private async Task numero2(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    var activity = await result as Activity;
    var num2 = activity.Text;
    await context.PostAsync($"El segundo número es {num2}");
    context.Wait(calcular);
}

private async Task calcular(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    Calculator.CalculatorSoapClient CS = new Calculator.CalculatorSoapClient();
    int final;
    final = CS.Add([acá iría el num1], [acá va el num2]);
}
```

Comment: Si la variable es definida dentro del metodo no se puede acceder a ella fuera de el.

Comment: Si la defino fuera, puedo hacer que contenga una respuesta del usuario? Porque lo intenté pero no pude

Comment: Si deberias poder.

Comment: Has probado a concatenar tareas con [ContinueWith](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ContinueWith_System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__) ?

Comment: Yo crearía una clase (supongamos **Numeros.cs**)con los parámetros num1, num2, respuesta. Y en cada llamada que haces le pasaría como parámetro la clase(**Numeros**) con datos y luego le haría retornar el objeto de la clase  **Numeros** quedaría algo así **private async Task<numeros> numero1(Numeros numeros) { //code }** y la misma historia para todos tus métodos, así cuando llegue al método **calcular** ya tendría el objeto numeros, con los datos necesarios.

Comment: ¿Por qué asignar los números son tareas asíncronas? , en lugar de enviar los números directamente a calcular

Comment: El lenguaje es C#.. pero todo este codigo no tiene nada de sentido. Estas trabajando con Xamarin? porque los numeros se piden en metodos? podrias aclarar que problema tuviste al sacar las variables fuera de los metodos?

Comment: Probaste guardar los numeros en variables 'globales' ,o si los numeros estan en 2 clases distintas, crea variables estaticas para accederlas